# Como forçar erro no retorno de uma Promise que esta dentro de outra Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
  const Firebird = require('node-firebird');
const { database } = require("../backend.conf");

async function pesqcdcidade(cidade) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        Firebird.attach(database, async function (err, db) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }

            const SQL = ' SELECT FIRST 1 CDCIDADE' +
                ' FROM CIDADES' +
                ' WHERE DESCRICAO =?';

            db.query(SQL, [cidade], async (err, resultParam) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                };

                if (resultParam != undefined) {
                    if (resultParam.length > 0) {
                        for (k = 0; k < resultParam.length; k++) {
                            resolve(resultParam[k]);
                        }
                    } else {

                        resolve("inexistente")
                    }
                } else {

                    resolve("inexistente")

                }

                db.detach();
            });
        });

    });


};
async function insertCidade(endereco) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        Firebird.attach(database, function (err, db) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }

            const SQL = ' INSERT INTO CIDADES (CDCIDADE, DESCRICAO, CDESTADO) ' +
                ' VALUES ((SELECT COALESCE(MAX(CDCIDADE), 0) + 1 ' +
                ' FROM CIDADES), ?, ?)';

            db.transaction(Firebird.ISOLATION_READ_COMMITED, function (err, transaction) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                }

                transaction.query(SQL, [endereco.cidade, endereco.uf], function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    }

                    transaction.commit(function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            transaction.rollback();
                            reject(err);

                        } else {
                            resolve("OK")
                            db.detach();
                        }
                    });
                });
            })
        });
    });
};
module.exports = app => {

    const insert = async (req, res) => {

        let strTesteDescri = "cidade exemplo";
        let cdcidade = 0;

        let cliente = {
            "endereco": {
                "cidade": "exemplo de cidade",
                "uf": "RS"
            }
        }


        try {
            await pesqcdcidade(strTesteDescri)
                .then(async (resultado) => {
                    if (resultado == 'inexistente') {
                        return await insertCidade(cliente.endereco)
                            .then(
                                await pesqcdcidade(strTesteDescri)
                                    .then(resultado => {
                                        if (resultado != 'inexistente') {
                                            cdcidade = resultado.CDCIDADE
                                        }

                                    })

                            )
                            .catch((err) => {
                                throw new Error('insertCidade failed');
                            })
                    } else {
                        cdcidade = resultado.CDCIDADE
                    }
                })

        } catch (eer) {
            return res.status(500).send(err);
        }
    }

}`insira o código aqui`
```

Comment: Antes de qualquer coisa, comece fazendo o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender como a comunidade funciona; depois leia o guia de [Como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) para verificar como pode melhorar sua pergunta.
Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas).

Comment: Valeime, reserve um segundo também para ler sobre o uso de [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) que irá te ajudar a organizar este código e eliminar estes `then` desnecessários.

Answer (score 2):

Duas opções:

- retirar esse `catch`
- retornar um novo erro dentro do `catch`.

A API async/await é muito prática mas cria dificuldades com a gestão de erros.

```js
async function teste() {
  const res = await Promise
    .resolve(foo())
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Erro interno', err);
      throw new Error('Erro 2');
    });
  return res;
}

function foo() {
  return Promise.reject('Erro 1');
}

teste().catch(err => console.log('Catch exterior', err.message));
```

Usa `throw new Error(...frase...)` para criar um novo erro e assim ele propaga para a o código que invocou essa linha.

Comment: Desculpe mas não entendi muito bem, sou novo no js, Essas funções que estão await conectam no firebird e por isso precisam ser executadas em sequencia e uma depende do resultado da outra...

Comment: @EzequielMenegás coloca `throw new Error('insertCidade failed');` onde tens `//ERRO GERADO AQUIII`

Comment: Pior que eu tentei isso mas ele não cai no catch externo

Comment: @EzequielMenegás tens de dar `return` em `await insertCidade`. A verdade é que esse código tem outros problemas para além do catch que discutimos aqui. Dá um `return`, mais que isso preciso de ver mais código para perceber e corrigir algumas coisas no teu encadeamento assíncrono

Comment: coloquei todo o tramite mas não esta dando certo, a minha estrutura esta meia confusa por não ter experiencia